# New-MailboxExportRequest Calander folder -ContentFilter date issue

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am attempting to export the calander folder of my users to .pst with all appointments prior to a specific date. The export functions without issue, however the contents of the export could be cleaner.

I would like the export to filter items who's *enddate* is 01/11/2018, rather than received prior. Currently, I am seeing all the appointments I accepted in Oct/Nov for December also in the .pst.

How do I change the `-Contentfilter {received -lt 01/11/2018}` to a hard cut of all items who's enddate is prior tio 01/11/2018?

My oneliner: `New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox User.McUserFace -IncludeFolders "#Calendar#" -contentfilter {received -lt '01/11/2018'} -filepath \\Server\User\User.McUserface\documents\CalanderArchive.pst`

Any help appreciated! I am on Exchange 2010.

Comment: In [the Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/filterable-properties-for-the-contentfilter-parameter) the only maybe filterable property I find would be `Expires`. Haven't tried though..

Answer (score 1):

Super-ExMerge may be able to help with this task.  One of the features is that filtering of contents is not done by a complicated query string, but instead, is handled by a PowerShell script block that you write to do the analysis with whatever complexity you desire.

Additionally, EVERY property of a message is accessible.  You may have to do some research on the exact property to retrieve, but it does give that power and flexibility.

Here's an example of exactly how such an export could be done:

```
$conn = New-ConnectionInfo joe@source.com exch01.source.com 'joe@source.com:Password' c:\export\joe.pst
$filter = New-ItemFilter -ItemProps PR_END_DATE -FilterScript { if($item.PR_END_DATE -gt [DateTime]'2018-01-11'){ $item.skip = $true } }
$task = New-SyncTask $conn -OneWaySyncSourceToTarget -SourceItemFilter $filter
add-SyncTask $task
```

In the above script example, the -ItemProp parameter specifies a list of mapi properties to retrieve before executing the -FilterScript.
In the -FilterScript, any item that should be skipped is marked by setting the special variable "$item.Skip" to $true.
In this example, any item with an end date greater than Nov 1, 2018 will be skipped.

Super-ExMerge is free to use up to a GB limit before throttling occurs.  For small use cases like this the free-use model is likely sufficient.  However, for larger exports and migration work, a paid-use upgrade can be made.

For full disclosure, i represent Priasoft - a 20+ year vendor of migration tools (since Exchange 5.5).
Priasoft has just released a new tool called Super-ExMerge that has attempted to modernize the old exmerge tool.  It's powershell based and very high performing.

If you're interested, here's the link:  Priasoft Super-ExMerge Tool for Office 365 and Exchange Server (https://www.priasoft.com/super-exmerge/)

For the full list of supporting powershell cmdlets: [Cmdlet Reference](https://www.priasoft.com/docs/superexmerge-on-line-documentation/cmdlet-reference/)

Answer (score 0):

You could export calendar items based on date using the below code:

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter {(Received -lt '04/01/2010') -and (Received -gt '03/01/2010')} -Mailbox "Pelton" -Name DPeltonExp -FilePath \\ExServer1\Imports\DPelton.pst
```

For more information, you could reference this link:

[Thoughtsofanidlemind's Blog](https://thoughtsofanidlemind.com/2011/10/21/date-range-exports-with-new-mailboxexportrequest/)